# Backbone.js How to shuffle items within a Collection

Tags: backbone.js, collections, model, shuffle

I'm having issues when trying to randomize the order of objects in a collection.

Here's the code that I've tried:

```
console.log(this.collection);
shuffled = this.collection.shuffle();
console.log(shuffled);
```

And here's the console output (using a test collection with 3 items):

```
child {models: Array[3], length: 3, _byId: Object, url: "/myurl/myid", _listenerId: "l7"…}
_byId: Object
_events: Object
_idAttr: "id"
_listenerId: "l7"
length: 3
models: Array[3]
__proto__: Surrogate

[child, child, child]
0: child
1: child
2: child
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
```

As you can see, the Collection is not being shuffled properly, instead it's creating a new unuseable object full of pesky children.

All I'm trying to do is randomize the order in which the models appear in the collection before passing it to a view for display (I'm creating a button called "randomize" which needs to randomize the display of the items in the collection).  I thought this would be an easy task, but at this point I'm considering just creating a whole new model and doing the shuffle on the server.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If if you want to randomise the view, why put the code in the collection and not the view?

Comment: The code is encapsulated in a view, I only was showing the related parts above.  The collection is randomized, then the view updated based on the randomized collection, and saved as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
console.log(this.collection);
this.collection.reset(this.collection.shuffle(), {silent:true});
console.log(this.collection);
```

Comment: Perfect!  This did the trick... I'll go have a look at the .reset function now.  Many thanks!

Comment: This is great. Would like this to be the default behavior of Backbone's implementation of _.shuffle